# Auto execute meterpreter commands on session start(android)

Tags: android, meterpreter

I want my meterpreter to execute the command as soon as it gets the session. My payload is `android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp`

I want a file that can execute these commands automatically as soon as meterpreter session is opened:

```
hide_app_icon
webcam_snap
```

What will be the commands to be put in an .rc file for android reverse_tcp?

Comment: this does nott explain the things to put in the.rc file.for andoid

Comment: Yes, the duplicate gives you more than enough for you to figure out your next steps.